# iPhone: how to append to end of text file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [iOS - appending to end of file with NSMutableString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106584/ios-appending-to-end-of-file-with-nsmutablestring)

Say I have a file at /var/mobile/Documents/myfile.txt

And that file contains

> Text
>
> Some more text

How can I append

> Even more text

to the end of that file?

Comment: Do you want to append text to that file programatically or manually?
programatically: do it like any other app does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779877/how-to-write-in-append-mode-for-text-file
manually: use any TextEditor in your iPhone you want

Comment: @Younes Jailbreaking is legal in US and most (all?) countries. See http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/07/feds-ok-iphone-jailbreaking/ I removed the jailbreaking tag because it is unrelated to the question. I also voted to close because it is duplicate of the question linked by thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Read the content of the file in NSMutableData.
convert the appended text to bytes and append the bytes to NSMutableData then write the NSMutableData to File

Comment: this is working but not elegant for large files because you load the hole file into memory which is not the case in the solution I postet in my comment on the question. direct-link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779877/how-to-write-in-append-mode-for-text-file