# How to save text file without overwritng in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I am trying to write NSString to the file. It is writing successfully however I want to append the new string to new line.

How can do this?

Comment: Do you have problem appending the string, or appending it on a new line?

Comment: i want to write /update my file periodically so i want previous data and new one also

Comment: Yes, but what is the current problem? That you overwrite the existing file everytime you write, causing old data to disappear?

Comment: yes correct i tried with seekToFileOffset of nsfile still not getting desired write .

Comment: And what is your current misbehaving code? Could you show us the code you got?

Comment: You can use seekToEndOfFile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779877/how-to-write-in-append-mode-for-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read file content, append new data to that content and save new data to a file you use:

```
// Here you set your appending text.    
NSString *yourAppendingText = @"yourAppendingText";  

// Here you get access to the file in Documents directory of your application bundle.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentFile = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.txt"];

// Here you read current existing text from that file
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
// Here you append new text to the existing one
NSString *textToFile = [textFromFile stringByAppendingString:yourAppendingText];
// Here you save the updated text to that file
[textToFile writeToFile:documentFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```