# Writing to file overrides previous line instead of writing a new line

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

So whenever I write to a file in my iPad app, it writes over the first line instead of writing to the next line down, so my file winds up only being a single line long and displays only the very last line of text.

This is the code I'm using to write to a file:

```
[myString writeToFile:filePath 
           atomically:YES 
             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                error:nil];
```

I also tried making it so "myString" ended in the character "\n" to see if that would make it skip a line but it didn't.

So if anyone knows what's wrong it'd really help me out.

Comment: writeToFile always overwrite the existing file. Try the answers found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779877/how-to-write-in-append-mode-for-text-file

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString* content = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];

[content appendString:yourNewString];
[content writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Hope this helps..